# cannot be cast to org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProviderInjector

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my spring project I am using hibernate for access database..

I have

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan-ref="packagesToScan"
        p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties" />

    <util:map id="hibernateProperties">
        <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <!-- <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> -->
        <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
    </util:map>

    <util:list id="packagesToScan">
        <value>com.preeti.myproject</value>
    </util:list>


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

In pom file I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I run that project I am getting error:

Error creating bean with name 'SignupController':

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Could not autowire field: 
private com.preeti.myproject.service.UserService 
com.preeti.myproject.controller.SignupController.userService
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userService': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
Could not autowire field:
 private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.preeti.myproject.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDao.sessionFactory;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext 
resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
 org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProviderInjector
```

when I used

```
 hibernate 3.5.0-final,
hibernate-core-3.5.4-Final,
hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.4-Final,
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga
```

that project has no error..

What I have to update to reduce this errors..

Comment: The jars for core and entity manager need to match. Make sure you have the same versions for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `project(right click)>properties>libraries`

delete all jars.

you have **pom.xml** file that means you are using maven.

So,go to terminal >locate your project then  run :

```
mvn clean install
```